# Javascript - These random numbers, why they don't work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate random numbers up to 899 and I can't know why this script doesn't work for me.

**[SEE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/huj7p528/)**

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="actualuno"><p>Oyentes en línea: </p><p id="ahorauno"></p></div>
```

**Script:**

```
function oyentes(){
  var n=Math.floor(899*Math.random()+1)
  document.getElementById("ahorauno").innerHTML=n
};
```

Comment: You never call `oyentes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `oyentes`:

```js
function oyentes() {
  var n = Math.floor(899 * Math.random() + 1);
  document.getElementById("ahorauno").innerHTML = n
};
oyentes()
```

```css
#actualuno {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

#actualuno p {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#ahorauno {
  margin-left: 6px !important
}
```

```html
<div id="actualuno">
  <p>Oyentes en línea: </p>
  <p id="ahorauno"></p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps,